# Firebase Analytics - Realtime works intermittently

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-analytics

My app uses Firebase Analytics to track usage. I'm testing my app locally and trying to view the Realtime analytics. Sometimes it works  and I can see my one realtime user and events, other times it doesn't showing anything. Most of the time I see no data. Sometimes, I can see my test events showing up in realtime, but the users still show 0. Why is Realtime working for Events occasionally but not users?

[image]

**However, as you can see in the below picture, there are no users.**

[image]

It's just me testing my app locally. Sometimes I see the "one" user, but other times I don't. Why is that?

I did notice in the logs this message

```
Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 3359909
```

That's in 55 minutes. So will I not see anything realtime for 55 minutes? Is it not really realtime?

Here is how I've implemented it:

```
project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "com.android.application"
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:19.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:20.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.0.0'
        ...
    }
    ...
}

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FirebaseAnalytics fb = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quote from an [article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/realtime-analytics-for-everyone.html) (it's a 2017 article, admittedly, but that's what I could find so far) that can get us started towards an answer:

"*StreamView visualizes events as they flow into Firebase Analytics [...]*"

(The Realtime view is akin to the StreamView.)

As you've noted above, whenever a new event is generated in your app, it gets scheduled for upload in a batch in order to save on network use, among other things. To the best of my understanding, this means that any event "flowing into" Firebase Analytics (**FA**) is an event that has dispatched in such a batch from your device. In your case, this can mean that the event that happened on minute 0 is "flowing into" FA on minute 55.

Now on to your questions.

> "Is it not really realtime?"

I believe it is realtime, but from the perspective of FA, not from the perspective of your app. While you're testing, this seems odd, because you're the one generating the event as well as observing it. I think they've designed the realtime view to observe usage when the app is out in the wild, in which case you might observe a set of events after some delay, but overall you'll keep seeing new events being recorded as if in realtime.

> "Sometimes it works and I can see my one realtime user and events, other times it doesn't showing anything. Most of the time I see no data. Sometimes, I can see my test events showing up in realtime, but the users still show 0."

Given that the above explanation is more or less correct, you can now see why you're seeing intermittent data.

Could you provide more details on:

- the way you are testing this,
- the delays that you are seeing between actual event and it being displayed on the console,
- the types of events (with params) that you are using while testing?

This could be helpful to anyone who is testing their FA implementation (e.g., me a few days ago).

---

**DebugView**

You might want to use DebugView to test your implementation and event data. [DebugView](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview) displays events in near-realtime from the perspective of your app. See the link for the implementation.

---

**Finally, some helpful things as you test:**

```
//(1)
// Allow events to be logged into DebugView at Firebase Console:
      $ adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app your.package.name
// And to disable:
      $ adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app .none.

//(2)
// Get live feedback on the logcat about Firebase Analytics actions:
      $ adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
      $ adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
      $ adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC

//(3)
// To enable debug logging for Crashlytics on the development device:
      $ adb shell setprop log.tag.FirebaseCrashlytics DEBUG
// To view the logs in your device logs:
      $ adb logcat -s FirebaseCrashlytics
// To disable debug logging:
      $ adb shell setprop log.tag.FirebaseCrashlytics INFO
```